# Android view position animation

Tags: android, android-animation

E.g

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <View1/>

    <View2
    above:view1/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a relativeLayout, and view2 is setup as above view1

Now I want to animate view2 to position blow view1

how Do I do that? is the animation has to use absolutely X/Y?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your relative layout:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

And then, in your code you could try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view2.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.view1);

view1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: It does changes the layout but without animation.
android:animateLayoutChanges="true" seems not working

Comment: Can you use a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout? If so, I can give you another alternative.

Comment: no, cause have some other components need to be in different layer and overlaped